# Windows mobile 6.0 network settings

Tags: windows-mobile

I am using Windows mobile 6.0 classic PDA's , I want to use wireless to access my service on the server(Win 2008), what should be my settings in the PDA network management? here's what my settings which works for some PDA's and for some it works for some time and stops? and for some PDA's similar settings does not work at all??

"Programs that connect to the internet..."   = ISP

"Programs that connect to a private network..." = My Work Network

BTW what is this My work network ??? i don't understand  as my PDA's use wireless (with proxy) i wud guess ISP to both should work right? but when i change second option to ISP as well the PDA that can connect to internet and server thru PDA IE but not through .netCF application will not get connected at all, but will work fine (apart from .netCF application accessing the server) if i change the second option back to My work network, so basically PDA is not using the first option of ISP at all ??

All i want to know is

1.) correct settings for WM 6.0 classic  wirelessly accesing server 2008 with proxy

2) explain what is my work network ?

Thanks

gauls

Comment: What language have you written your application in, and have you written it to cope with proxies?

Comment: @ Rowland Shaw : vb.net compact frame work, nope